# Why sqlalchemy postgres engine connection commits automatically?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, autocommit

For some reason engine connection commits automatically, which is not desired. I want to commit explicitly. Here's my code ([it repeats official tutorial verbatim](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/index.html)):

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@localhost:5432/test_db', echo=True)

mapper_registry = registry()
Base = mapper_registry.generate_base()

user_table = Table(
    "user_account",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("name", String(30)),
    Column("fullname", String),
)

mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(engine)

stmt = insert(user_table).values(name="spongebob", fullname="Spongebob Squarepants")
print(stmt)
    
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(stmt)
    # conn.commit()
```

Even without commit my logs are:

```
INSERT INTO user_account (name, fullname) VALUES (:name, :fullname)
2023-02-09 16:12:05,033 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO user_account (name, fullname) VALUES (%(name)s, %(fullname)s) RETURNING user_account.id
2023-02-09 16:12:05,034 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00123s] {'name': 'spongebob', 'fullname': 'Spongebob Squarepants'}
2023-02-09 16:12:05,037 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

And new object appears in the database.
I tried to set `conn.execution_options(isolation_level="SERIALIZABLE")` and
`create_engine(...).execution_options(isolation_level="SERIALIZABLE")` with no success

However when I set `isolation_level` to `"AUTOCOMMIT"`, logs are slightly different (so I'm sure isolation_level option is interpreted correctly):

```
INSERT INTO user_account (name, fullname) VALUES (:name, :fullname)
2023-02-09 16:17:35,889 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO user_account (name, fullname) VALUES (%(name)s, %(fullname)s) RETURNING user_account.id
2023-02-09 16:17:35,890 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00132s] {'name': 'spongebob', 'fullname': 'Spongebob Squarepants'}
2023-02-09 16:17:35,893 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT using DBAPI connection.commit(), DBAPI should ignore due to autocommit mode
```

```
sqlalchemy.__version__
'1.4.46'
```

What's the reason of such behavior?

What do I not understand?

What am I missing?

Thanks

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

As @snakecharmerb pointed, with `fututre=true` it works as expected (and this is the only significant difference with the docs).

```py
engine = create_engine('...url', echo=True, future=True**)
```

So this flag changes autocommit behavior.

```
INSERT INTO user_account (name, fullname) VALUES (:name, :fullname)
2023-02-09 17:42:08,499 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-02-09 17:42:08,499 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO user_account (name, fullname) VALUES (%(name)s, %(fullname)s) RETURNING user_account.id
2023-02-09 17:42:08,500 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00085s] {'name': 'spongebob', 'fullname': 'Spongebob Squarepants'}
<sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult object at 0x7fef30f76ac0>
2023-02-09 17:42:10,511 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
```

It answers my question mostly, but I'm still curious if I can have similar behavior without `future=True`, because I cannot turn it on (for the project I work on) yet

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy do you have installed?

Comment: @snakecharmerb 1.4.46

Comment: Does it work as you expect if you add `future=True` to the call to `create_engine`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yeah, now it behaves as expected. Howeher, can I have similar result without `future=True`? Because I cannot turn on this flag yet for the project I work on yet

Comment: @yevt does `with engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=False) as conn` work?

Comment: @python_user You're right it does

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Now it's clear. `autocommit` and `isolation_level` are different things. *(They should be related, but that is out of the scope of the current question)*

1. `autocommit` is **off** by default if `future=True`, and **on** by default otherwise.
2. If you cannot set `future=True` but still want `autocommit` to be **off** you have 2 options (at least):

2.1 Pass `autocommit=false` to `connection`:

```py
with engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=False) as conn
```

2.2 Pass `autocommit=false` to `engine`:

```py
engine = create_engine('...dburl', echo=True).execution_options(autocommit=False)
```